# How to disable part of the code in eclipse without including the code in multiline comment, or any other comment?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to java and eclipse, and I have noticed that in some cases when I have some class with several methods, I want to run only one method and disable other methods, and the only solution that I'm using now is to put the methods inside a  multiline comment, I wish that there is an option in eclipse to select a section from the code and press some button and just to disable that part, I mean also the compilation.
Please assist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Disable other methods? Because you aren’t done with them?!

Comment: yes, they aren't done,
but I found a solution that is working for me ctrl+ /
thanks' a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable parts of your code completely because they could be called from somewhere. You’d get a lot of Errors/Exceptions and your program wouldn’t work as expected.

But you can select a section from the code in Eclipse and press `CTRL + SHIFT + 7` to comment a section out and the same combination to remove the comment and to 're-enable' the code.

Comment: thank you, 
I found that (ctrl+ /) working for me perfectly